# blank spaces on a html/css page

Tags: html, css

blank spaces on the top margin and on href line. tried fixing with margin=0 and width=100% but nothing changed

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61); 
  font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}
```

```
<ul> 
        <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a><li>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgettoWeb/portfolio.html" target="_blank" font="arial" >PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgettoWeb/aboutme.html" target="_blank" >ABOUT ME</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/ProgettoWeb/contacts.html" target="_blank" >CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
```

tried fixing with width and margin but it seems pretty much the same.

Comment: Can you please provide an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a small css reset when you add this lines below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: this apparently solved it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this has something to do with the browser adding margin. Try setting the margin in your body element to 0

Comment: what a lot of people miss is that the browser comes with its own style sheet built in, and if you don't want them margins you need to specifically set them to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The body element naturally comes with some margin.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```